# Paypal REST API INSTRUMENT_DECLINED error recovery

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using Paypal REST to process payments.

Recently I've got INSTRUMENT_DECLINED error from my user.

- User has been billed from his credit card and redirected to Success endpoint.
- API returned INSTRUMENT_DECLINED error, so my UI has shown Error 500.
- I can't see the payment in paypal admin ui.
- User lost his money. He feels upset.

It seems to be a common problem, handled well in Classic API:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/

So in Classic API if I get an error, I just redirect a user back to Paypal, so that Paypal guides him. Paypal knows what happened and what to do, it's ok.

But I can't find any docs about processing error recovery in REST API.

Should I hack into classic express checkout with my REST-gathered data?

Or is there any proper way to make the good user experience in case of a problem on paypal's side?

Comment: I'm unclear: if you get "INSTRUMENT_DECLINED" & do not see a payment, the user should not have lost any money. Why do you say the user has lost his money?

Comment: @geewiz yep client have sent me a screenshot with SMS from his bank. So paypal took money. Maybe it will make a refund. Very unhappy client.

Comment: Please contact PayPal support, or have the buyer do so. This should never happen and PayPal will definitely get the buyer the money back (and fix this bug as high priority). Sorry for your experience, though. Until PayPal fixes the underlying problem on their end, however, I don't think you have any good options. I would not "hack" into EC with REST info; the REST product already uses some of the EC user interface, but if PayPal does not know how to make the connection themselves then it is unlikely they will handle the situation correctly if you try to do it.